# Spotipy - OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, https, port, spotipy

I'm using SageMaker in AWS on a Notebook instance and I am receiving
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
when connecting to Spotify API through Spotipy.

I read countless threads and questions about this and all of them point to kill the service using the port but the service running is my python kernel, if I kill it, it kills my notebook, tried to run again and same story.

Anyone has any ideas?

In my local machine, exact same code is working fine.

[image: Error]

[image: Port]

Comment: please paste some error or traceback.

Comment: @shivankgtm added

Comment: Your code is trying to start an HTTP server and there is already an HTTP server running on the specified port. Stop the existing service and then run your code.

Comment: @jordanm I tried that already and it kills my python kernel, after restarting and run again it causes the same issue.